# How do I restrict host only to specific URIs?

Tags: nginx

My host (`dev.foo.com`) has a map such as the following. Approximately 1000 entries.

```
rewrite ^/2f7f29e4-14be-564a-85e0-5bb29b9fc33f/(.*)$ "/gajus kuizinas/2012 04 03 gappery/$1" last;
rewrite ^/cb6e7269-75c0-5926-b5d5-4e625e1a320d/(.*)$ "/gajus kuizinas/2012 04 07 gappery/$1" last;
rewrite ^/8b96e14f-09cd-55a5-9de3-19775b5ee2bb/(.*)$ "/gajus kuizinas/2012 05 17 followem/$1" last;
```

Is there a way to restrict host only to URIs that start with one of the given UUIDs? In other words, make any other paths inaccessible, such as `dev.foo.com/public/[..]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location / {
    return 403;
}

location ~ ^/\w{8}-(?:\w{4}-){3}\w{12}/ {
    ...
}
```

- http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
- http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside your server or location directive:

```
    if ($request_uri !~ "^/\w{8}-(?:\w{4}-){3}\w{12}/.*") {
        return 403;
    }
```

So, as the doc says,

$request_uri
This variable is equal to the *original* request URI as received from the client including the args. It cannot be modified. Look at $uri for the post-rewrite/altered URI. Does not include host name. Example: "/foo/bar.php?arg=baz"

If $request_uri doesn't match to your uuid regex, then nginx returns 403 error (access denied).

---

Edit: 503 to 403 in the `if`.

Comment: Good answer, though, not sure why did you use `503` rather than `403` in return statement.